# Dictionary not assigning correct values in a for loop

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have 2-column data in a Numpy array and I want to create a dictionary out of the pairs of values. Data looks something like this -

```
[[0.000e+00 1.510e+02] 
 [1.000e+00 1.410e+02]
 [2.000e+00 1.490e+02]
 ...
 [2.238e+03 1.580e+02]
 [2.239e+03 1.520e+02]
 [2.240e+03 1.620e+02]]
```

The Code is:

```
data = np.loadtxt('neon_spectrum.txt', delimiter=' ') # Loads data into Numpy array as shown above
neon_dictionary = {}
for (x, y) in data:       
      neon_dictionary[y] = x
print(neon_dictionary)
```

Expected result: `{151.0:0.0, 141.0:1.0, 149.0:2.0 ... 162.0:2240.0}`
Actual result (Keys are correct, Values are junk): `{151.0:265.0, 141.0:539.0, ...}`

No error messages. I can't figure out what mistake I am making in the dictionary assignment. Thanks.

Comment: print data to see how your data is structured

Comment: How I have shown it above is how it is structured when I print it. It is a standard 2D numpy array when loading two columns of data.